# Mono for Android is a framework that need to be installed on android devices or is a compiler that compiles to java bytecode?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to understand how mono for android works and I'm not found this explanation in official site.

Taking into account that android reads java bytecode, Mono for Android is a framework that need to be installed on android devices or is a compiler that compiles to java byte code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) on Xamarin's site describes how the architecture is put together.

Long story short, there is nothing compiling C# into Java byte code. Mono for Android applications ship with the Mono runtime embedded in them, which runs side by side with Dalvik (Android's Java virtual machine). The Mono runtime uses callable wrappers in order to facilitate communicating back and forth with Dalvik when needed, but .NET objects talk right to the Mono runtime, rather than Dalvik.

To speed up development, apps in debug mode are set up to use a shared runtime to cut down on deployment time, and allowing multiple apps to share the same runtime. This isn't supported for applications compiled in release mode, though, so any app you release and distribute will contain its own embedded Mono runtime, and will not have a dependency on anything else.

Comment: Please, you can explain in a detailed mode when Mono runtime will need to communicating with Dalvik? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The article I linked to explains it better, and in more detail, than I could. In particular, read the parts about callable wrappers. Basically, anything that needs to access the Java/Android side of things will be communicating with Dalvik, i.e., anything that inherits from Java.Lang.Object.

Answer (score 0):

From this article

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/introducing-monodroid-intro.aspx/

> MonoTouch creates a native application that contains the Mono runtime
>   embedded within the application. MonoDroid can create two types of
>   applications. The first is a single standalone application, which is
>   similar to a MonoTouch application, with the app and the Mono runtime
>   bound together. Everything that the application needs is embedded
>   within the application. The second type is an application that makes
>   use of a shared runtime that's installed on the device. This is
>   similar to how .NET apps run on Windows. With this type of
>   application, the app, along with other applications written with
>   MonoDroid, can make use of a shared runtime.

Comment: The last part of this is no longer totally accurate. The shared runtime still exists in the context of debug versions of apps to help speed up deployments during testing, but it is not supported for apps being released.