# How does MonoRuntime lives side-by-side with ART?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mono

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11633911/4074227) that applications which are being developed using Mono are deployed with a MonoRuntime that works similar as ART, interprets the C# code, executes them etc. I assume Unity and Xamarin both does this.

What is strange for me is that theoretically I could write a runtime and ship it with my app? But that is supposed to be next to the [runtime](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-3dfdc6df9d013aeeb0e545b9e3dcf82c), below the application framework? How can the sandboxing let this happen?

I assume [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) might be the solution to my confusion, but I struggle understanding it.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First think about how NDK/JNI apps work on Android. They are launched from standard Android Java code run via ART/Dalvik and use JNI calls into C/C++ code. The process is still within the standard Android 'sandbox' but has additional lower level access to libraries provided by Android NDK headers. As that code is written in C/C++ it can be performant/cross system compatible.

So to answer:

> But that is supposed to be next to the runtime, below the application framework?

I would argue no, at least you aren't really below the Android application framework. The MonoRuntime is started from Android and can use any of the 'Standard Libraries' which are exposed either via a JNI wrapper to the Android Java side or by a NDK header.

If you look at the below diagram you'll see 'Standard Libraries' which can be OpenGL ES which has a Android Java API and OpenSL ES which exposes more detail in NDK than the Android Java media api.

[image: NDK app]

> I could write a runtime and ship it with my app?

Yes you could, although you may want to define clearly what you mean by 'runtime'. If you are pre-compiled you can strip out unnecessary classes/modules which I believe Mono does.

> How can the sandboxing let this happen?

You are still in the sandbox. Nothing prevents you from writing your own interpreter / Virtual Machine written in C/C++, interfacing the Android framework through standard JNI/NDK calls, and adding it to your own APK. Regardless you are still limited to what the Android framework/runtime allows for apps along with same process restrictions and limitations.

Comment: You already provide a good answer on Xamarin.Android. However, Unity on Android is completely different. Unity developed its own technology called IL2CPP, and compile all MSIL to C++ source files and then compile and linked to a native package, so similar to Android NDK apps.